# How do you set images from JavaScript that change according to time of day to be the background?

Tags: javascript, css, image, dom, background

My HTML has a <img> tag with an id="image_1". My JavaScript function tells the time of day and according to the time of day changes between three images. Im wanting the Images to appear as my background.

- I tried messing around with the DOM manipulation background property.
- I've tried using CSS to make the image/images appear as the background.

all resulted in the image staying the same with no effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Clock & Greeting</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Clock.css" />
  </head>
  <body onLoad="startTime();">
    <div id="greeting"></div>

    <div id="txt"></div>

    <img src="" alt="" id="image_1" />

    <script src="Clock.js" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
    const greeting = document.getElementById("greeting");
    const welcomeTypes = ["Good Morning", "Good Afternoon", "Good evening"];
    const hour = new Date().getHours();
    
    function startTime() {
      const today = new Date();
      let h = today.getHours();
      let m = today.getMinutes();
      let s = today.getSeconds();
      m = checkTime(m);
      s = checkTime(s);
      document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
      setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
    }
    
    function checkTime(i) {
      if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
      }
      return i;
    }
    
    let welcomeTxt = "";
    
    if (hour < 12) welcomeTxt = welcomeTypes[0];
    else if (hour <= 18) welcomeTxt = welcomeTypes[1];
    else welcomeTxt = welcomeTypes[2];
    
    greeting.innerHTML = welcomeTxt;
    
var day = new Date();
var today = parseInt(day.getDay());
var hours = parseInt(day.getHours());
var minutes = parseInt(day.getMinutes());
var imgElem = document.getElementById("image_1");

(function () {
  if (today >= 0 && today <= 6) {
    if (hours < 12) {
      imgElem.src =
        "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1332712244/photo/sunrise-over-misty-fields-of-corn.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=Ahdwy0nHLDDxMPA5Q9D6bUBykhjixiqVWFvsiX9E6aE=";
    } else if (hours <= 18) {
      imgElem.src =
        "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/141467949/photo/beach-at-bamburgh-northumberland-uk.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=5kfMaNJIVWffH629lmkxjt6uXx58fQyxPtf2w4rhhs8=";
    } else {
      imgElem.src =
        "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1432902897/photo/the-star-shines-on-the-christmas-eve-of-jesus-christ.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=DLHO1CgZ8yqwy2S5hx_jopHOSh6OE_ew0oZUxW1ivmo=";
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Hi, have you had a chance to check my answer to see if it helps? Please let me know if you have any additional questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current implementation, you update your background image only once when the script is executed right after it is loaded.

To change the background dynamically, you need to check if the background needs to be updated repeatedly, for example, like so:

```
function updateBackground() {
    var day = new Date();
    var today = day.getDay();
    var hours = day.getHours();
    var imgElem = document.getElementById("image_1");
    if (today >= 0 && today <= 6) {
        if (hours < 12) {
            imgElem.src =
                "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1332712244/photo/sunrise-over-misty-fields-of-corn.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=Ahdwy0nHLDDxMPA5Q9D6bUBykhjixiqVWFvsiX9E6aE=";
        } else if (hours <= 18) {
            imgElem.src =
                "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/141467949/photo/beach-at-bamburgh-northumberland-uk.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=5kfMaNJIVWffH629lmkxjt6uXx58fQyxPtf2w4rhhs8=";
        } else {
            imgElem.src =
                "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1432902897/photo/the-star-shines-on-the-christmas-eve-of-jesus-christ.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=DLHO1CgZ8yqwy2S5hx_jopHOSh6OE_ew0oZUxW1ivmo=";
        }
    }
}

setInterval(updateBackground, 1000);
```

If you are wondering how you can improve your code even further, I would change it like so:

```
const welcomeTypes = [
    {
        backgroundUrl: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1332712244/photo/sunrise-over-misty-fields-of-corn.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=Ahdwy0nHLDDxMPA5Q9D6bUBykhjixiqVWFvsiX9E6aE=',
        message: "Good Morning",
    },
    {
        backgroundUrl: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/id/141467949/photo/beach-at-bamburgh-northumberland-uk.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=5kfMaNJIVWffH629lmkxjt6uXx58fQyxPtf2w4rhhs8=',
        message: "Good Afternoon",
    },
    {
        backgroundUrl: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1432902897/photo/the-star-shines-on-the-christmas-eve-of-jesus-christ.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=DLHO1CgZ8yqwy2S5hx_jopHOSh6OE_ew0oZUxW1ivmo=',
        message: "Good evening",
    }
];

const padWithZero = (i) => (i < 10 ? '0' + i : i);

const updateClock = (h, m, s) => {
    m = padWithZero(m);
    s = padWithZero(s);
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}

const getPartOfTheDayIndex = (h) => {
    if (h < 12) return 0;
    else if (h <= 18) return 1;
    return 2;
}

const updateWelcomeText = (part) => {
    const greeting = document.getElementById("greeting");
    if (greeting !== greeting.innerHTML) {
        greeting.innerHTML = welcomeTypes[part].message;
    }
}

const updateBackground = (d, part) => {
    const imgElem = document.getElementById("image_1");
    if (d >= 0 && d <= 6) {
        const backgroundUrl = "url('" + welcomeTypes[part].backgroundUrl + "')";
        if (document.body.style.backgroundImage !== backgroundUrl) {
            document.body.style.backgroundImage = backgroundUrl;
            document.body.style.backgroundSize = 'Cover';
        }
    }
}


const startTime = () => {
    const today = new Date();
    const d = today.getDay();
    const h = today.getHours();
    const m = today.getMinutes();
    const s = today.getSeconds();
    const part = getPartOfTheDayIndex(h);
    updateClock(h, m, s);
    updateWelcomeText(part);
    updateBackground(d, part);
    setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}
```

Improvements:

- Date & time requested only once
- Part of the day evaluated only once
- Greeting message and background URL are stored together for easier association
- Part of the day logic is easier to test
- Modern arrow functions

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: The tips and code organization were very helpful but what I'm shooting for is for the images to become the background of my webpage and when using your code it didn't do so. Thankyou for your time btw!

Comment: @Lorins__Web No worries. I've updated the second code. It sets an image as a `body` background now. Is this what you are looking for?